# dep ensure fails with Solving failure: failed to clean up git repository .

Tags: go, dep

I am trying to import the go repo 
`https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli`

My `dep init` or `dep ensure` commands fail when I add the import statement in my go program.

I am not sure what is the reason I am not able to get the repo. I can do a `git clone` in the go/src and it complains that the local version might be inconsistent.

Not sure what is happening with this particular repo.

```
bash-3.2$ dep ensure
Solving failure: failed to clean up git repository at /Users/rjain/go/pkg/dep/sources/https---github.com-cloudfoundry-cli - dirty? corrupted? status output: 
 D VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because this repo has a massive number of submodules, and some of them are private repos, and some of them no longer exists. Try running `dep ensure -v` and you'll see the errors. It seems that dep tries to check out every submodule.

If I was you, I would identify the submodule I need and import that directly.